# Issue pushing an element in an array.(array_push)

Tags: php

I did this php code

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['id']) or !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    extract($_GET);
    $id = strip_tags($id);
    require_once 'config/functions.php';

    $errors = array();

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        extract($_POST);

        $author = strip_tags($author);
        $comment = strip_tags($comment);

        if (empty($author)) {
            $errors = array_push($errors, 'Entre a nickname');
        }

        if (empty($comment)) {
            $errors = array_push($errors, 'Entre a comment');
        }

        var_dump($comment);
        var_dump($author);
        var_dump($errors);
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $comment = addComment($id, $author, $comment);
            $sucess = 'Your comment has been sent';
            unset($author);
            unset($comment);
        }
    }
    $article = getArticle($id);
    $comments = getComments($id);
}
```

However, when I submitted the form I saw that every time the submission was successful so I decided to dump the variables $errors , $comment and $author to try to solve the issue. Here, the array $errors no matter what was empty. I tried not to put the comment or the author or even both but it still isn't working.
Could you help me out with this problem guys because I really don't know from where it comes from?

Comment: You assign the result to the array: `$errors = array_push($errors`, that is not what you want

Comment: **Warning** Do not use `extract()` on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. `$_GET`, `$_FILES`).

Comment: Just do `$errors[] = 'Entre a comment';`

Comment: What do you see for `var_dump($comment);` and `var_dump($author);`?

Comment: `var_dump($author);` gives me **string(8) "nickname"** and `var_dump($comment);` returns **string(10) "a comment "**

Answer (score 0):

In PHP [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is a function which allows you to push multiple elements into the array, and the result of that function is the number of elements added. The array itself is passed as reference in the first argument.
However, you do not need to call this function.

> **Note:** If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array, it's better to use *`$array[] =`* because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

You can just use the [array append operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

```
if(!$comment) {
    $errors[] = 'Entre a comment';
}
```

On unrelated note, you should never trust user input. Do not `extract()` your `$_GET` or `$_POST` super-globals!

Comment: Thank you for your answer I changed my code as you indicated me however the dumped array is still empty